# Django on Heroku connecting to Azure Database

Tags: python, django, azure, heroku

I'm deploying a Django application onto Heroku.  I have my app wired up to a legacy database located on Azure.  I've been using the django-pyodbc-azure package and have had no issues connecting to the Azure DB via my local development server.  But when I try to access via production, I get a message stating:

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?  I can't find much documentation on this specific issue.

Thanks.